# Curvature of functions in $R$

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be any real valued function on $R$. Let $a$ be any point in $R$ then how we can calculate radius of curvature of the function $f$ at point $a$?

Comment: You mean the radius of curvature of the graph considered as a planar curve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your real valued function is $y=f(x)$.  The radius of curvature is defined as:
$$
R=\left| \frac{ds}{d\theta}\right|
$$
where $s$ is the arc length and $\theta$ is the tangent angle.

We have: 
$$ds^2=dx^2+dy^2 \Rightarrow \frac{ds}{dx}=\sqrt{1+y'^2}$$

$$
\tan \theta = \frac {dy}{dx} \Rightarrow \theta= \arctan (y') \Rightarrow \frac{d \theta}{dx}=\frac{y''}{1+y'^2}
$$
so:
$$
R=\left| \frac{\frac{ds}{dx}}{\frac{d\theta}{dx}}\right|=\left|\frac{\sqrt{1+y'^2}(1+y'^2)}{y''} \right|
$$

Answer (score 0):

As curvature is independent of torsion and invariable for rigid movements, you can think $f$ as a function $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^3$ given by $F(t)=(t,f(t),0)$ and calculate curvature in the usual way.

Then, calculate radius of curvature.